# React Native DEV and PROD variables

Tags: react-native

How do I know if my React Native app is running in production or development? Is there some sort of way within JavaScript to tell? Is there a global that is passed in?

Comment: FYI, I was getting this when importing a Component in `react-native` in my `globalSetup` file. Moving this setup from `globalSetup` to `setupFilesAfterEnv` did the trick, since the `jest` test environment is loaded before the files listed in `setupFilesAfterEnv` are run.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You can use the `__DEV__` global variable in JavaScript to determine if you're using React Native packager or not. If you are running your app in the iOS Simulator or Android emulator `__DEV__` will be set to `true`.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/javascript-environment

Comment: Also if you are running the app on a physical device using `react-native run-*`

Comment: What about when you run in a simulator with `--configuration Release`? Does this still use the React Native packager and set `__DEV__` to `true`?

Comment: @Marklar when running in release configuration, the `__DEV__` is NOT set to true in my experience.

Comment: `__DEV__` is only about the build configuration. If you want to detect whether the app is running on device or in a simulator, use something like `react-native-device-info`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `__DEV__` variable.
By default if you run your app with `npx react-native run-ios` or `npx react-native run-android`, it will run in Debug mode and `__DEV__` will be true.
In release mode, `__DEV__` will be false.
You can use it this way:

```
const CLOUD_API_BASE_URL = __DEV__ ? 'https://api-dev.yourdomain.com' : 'https://api-prod.yourdomain.com';
```

You can run the app in Release mode with the terminal:
`react-native run-android --variant release` #android
`react-native run-ios --configuration Release` #ios

Or open the ios folder in XCode, choose Product > Scheme > Edit Schemes
[image: xcode edit scheme]
Select Run in the left menu. For Build Configuration, choose 'Release' and uncheck 'Debug executable'

[image]

In Android Studio, similarly, you can set the build variant to `release`
[image]

Comment: what if I have multiple variant (uat , sit, prod ) and not just simple (debug or release) , I want to know exactly where is that piece of toggle in build gradle turning __DEV__ true or false , i cannot find any resource telling me to do this

Answer (score 3):

When the `__DEV__` variable is set to `true`, it turns on a bunch of useful development warnings. For production, it is recommended to set `__DEV__=false`.

Comment: how can I toogle this?

Comment: Where do we set __Dev__ to true though? React Native, Expo sdk 42

Comment: You didn't specify anyway to go about this. How does someone set to false?

Answer (score -3):

I didn't intend to write an answer, but I'm not able to comment (<50 pts). To toggle `__DEV__`, you can set it before your command, e.g.:

`__DEV__=true expo start` (should already be set to true though)

or

`__DEV__=false react-native run-ios` (should be set to true by default, when running this command without setting manually)

Comment: All other answers already made that clear. Even a comment wasn't necessary.

Comment: Does this work for you? It doesn't for me. `__DEV__` is not a normal environment variable so it can't be set like this.