# React Native - What is the benefit of using StyleSheet vs a plain object?

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

What exactly is the benefit of using `StyleSheet.create()` vs a plain object?

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
}
```

Vs.

```js
const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
}
```

Comment: I get VSCode intellisense support for properties. That's the benefit.

Comment: When used with ``react-native-web``, ``StyleSheet.create`` creates a new CSS class whereas a vanilla object gets attached as inline styles

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Quoting directly from comment section of [StyleSheet.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/8eed600d5b2be78c405f7ef139a7b0e4a2480c85/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js) of React native

> Code quality:
>
> - By moving styles away from the render function, you're making the  code easier to understand.
> - Naming the styles is a good way to add meaning to the low level components in the render function.
>
> Performance:
>
> - Making a stylesheet from a style object makes it possible to refer to it by ID instead of creating a new style object every time.
> - It also allows to send the style only once through the bridge. All subsequent uses are going to refer an id (not implemented yet).

Also StyleSheet validates your stylesheet content as well. So any error of incorrect style property is shown at time of compiling rather than at runtime when StyleSheet is actually implemented.

Comment: I see, I was wondering because I can just use an object so what's the point of StyleSheet. Also, is inline better than StyleSheet when it comes to performance?

Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: No. Inline is not efficient as well. It is similar to using normal object. Because with inline style as well react native will need to send more data to React native bridge as compared to stylesheet. Which is not good for performance

Comment: The first three bullet points are irrelevant of OP's technique of declaring the style object as a const outside the render function.

Comment: My thoughts as Owen exactly. I worked through tutorials that just used the OP's technique, and then I came across this stylesheet function and couldn't figure out what the point was.

So the only perk is the compile-time validation.

I'd appreciate if someone can elaborate on the last bullet point.

Comment: When I read the explanation I still don't see how `StyleSheet.create({styles...})` is better/faster than `{styles...}`. The code is just as clean, and you're also using naming instead of inlining. Can anyone shed some light on it?

Comment: `StyleSheet` provides validation at compilation

Comment: Downvoted. Don't put irrelevant information ("by moving styles away from the render function", etc.) in your answer.

Comment: Downvoted, the question of the OP was the difference between `StyleSheet.create` and a plain Object, not inline vs a const outside the class

Comment: Downvoted for not giving a relevant answer. There are no differences between them except of typing normalization in TypeScript.

Comment: react-native docs [removed](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet) the bullet point referencing "send the style only once through the bridge".

Comment: If you're using react-native-web (for example the expo bare workflow and yarn web script), there is a big difference. StyleSheet.create will generate atomic css classes whereas a regular style object will result in inline styles:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63585152/how-to-generate-class-names-instead-of-inline-styles-for-react-native-web

Answer (score 111):

There is no benefit. Period.

#### Myth 1: `StyleSheet` is more performant

There is absolutely no performance difference between `StyleSheet` and an object declared outside of `render` (it would be different if you're creating a new object inside `render` every time). The performance difference is a myth.

The origin of the myth is likely because React Native team tried to do this, but they weren't successful. Nowhere in the official docs you will find anything about performance: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html, while source code states "not implemented yet": https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js#L207

#### Myth 2: `StyleSheet` validates style object at compile time

This is not true. Plain JavaScript can't validate objects at compile time.

Two things:

- It does validate at runtime, but so does when you pass the style object to a component. No difference.
- It does validate at compile time **if you're using Flow or TypeScript**, but so does once you pass the object as a style prop to a component, or if you properly typehint object like below. No difference either.

```js
const containerStyle: ViewStyle = {
   ...
}
```

Comment: True.  Perhaps the confusion comes from the earlier version of their docs implying that they were eventually going to reference styles by id.  That isn't mentioned in the 0.59 docs.

Comment: THX for demystifying. But question is open - What for ?

Comment: Plus about p2 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/8eed600d5b2be78c405f7ef139a7b0e4a2480c85/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js#L169

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It deserves more upvotes :)

Comment: so using StyleSheet is completely... useless?

Comment: My testing indicates that it _does_ validate at runtime without need to pass to a component, e.g. `StyleSheet.create( {x:{flex: "1"}} )` will fail at runtime, as will a typescript check on this at compile time.

Comment: Also its better to use `StyleSheet.create(` instead simple object is because of future proof. :)

Comment: even in the doc, they said referring by ID is `"(not implemented yet)."`

Comment: I think it's a good practice to use `Stylesheet.create` because in the feature they may implement it's referring by ID feature and we don't need to refactor our code

Comment: I would have imagined that StyleSheet could do some optimizations e.g. parse color strings into an object 

Answer (score 25):

The accepted answer is not an answer to the OP question.

The question is not the difference between inline styles and a `const` outside the class, but why we should use `StyleSheet.create` instead of a plain object.

After a bit of researching what I found is the following (please update if you have any info).
The advantages of `StyleSheet.create` should be the following:

1. It validates the styles
2. Better perfomance because it creates a mapping of the styles to an ID, and then it refers inside with this ID, instead of creating every time a new object. So even the process of updating devices is faster because you don't send everytime all the new objects.

Comment: These are myths. Check my answer.

Comment: If I define the style object outside of the class (or even as a class property) it will be created once (or once per instance). The same objects being created again is only relevant inside functions.

Comment: Yeah for the const, but class property nope. Static class property yep.

Answer (score 11):

It used to be considered that using a StyleSheet was more performant, and *was* [recommended](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.57/stylesheet) for this reason by the RN team up until version 0.57, but it is now no longer recommended as correctly pointed out in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52630543/857209) to this question.

The [RN documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.60/stylesheet) now recommends StyleSheet for the following reasons, though I think these reasons would apply equally to plain objects that are created outside of the render function:

- By moving styles away from the render function, you're making the
  code easier to understand.
- Naming the styles is a good way to add meaning to the low level
  components in the render function.

So what do I think *are* the possible benefits of using StyleSheet over plain objects?

1) Despite claims to the contrary my testing on RN v0.59.10 indicates that you *do* get some validation when calling `StyleSheet.create()` and typescript (and probably flow) will also report errors at compile time. Even without compile time checking I think it's still beneficial to do run time validation of styles *before* they are used for rendering, particularly where components that use those styles could be conditionally rendered. This will allow such errors to be picked up without having to test all rendering scenarios.

2) Given that StyleSheet *is* recommended by the RN team they may still have hopes of using StyleSheet to improve performance in future, and they may have other possible improvements in mind as well, for example:

3) The current `StyleSheet.create()` run-time validation is useful, but a bit limited. It seems to be restricted to the type checking that you would get with flow or typescript, so will pick up say `flex: "1"` or `borderStyle: "rubbish"`, but not `width: "rubbish"` as that could be a percentage string. It's possible that the RN team may improve such validation in future by checking things like percentage strings, or range limits, or you could wrap `StyleSheet.create()` in your own function to do that more extensive validation.

4) By using StyleSheet you are perhaps making it easier to transition to third party alternatives/extensions like [react-native-extended-stylesheet](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet) that offer more.

Answer (score 8):

So, today, **September of 2021**, after reading all the answers and doing some researches, I created a summary about using `Stylesheet` instead of a plain object.

1. Based on [React Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/style), you should use the stylesheet when the complexity starts to grow.

> The style prop can be a plain old JavaScript object. That's what we usually use for example code.
> As a component grows in complexity, it is often cleaner to use StyleSheet.create to define several styles in one place.

2. In the simulator, when using stylesheet will display an **ERROR**, and when using the plain object will display only a **WARNING**.
3. Based on item 2, it looks like it has some validation while compiling. (A lot of people say that’s a myth)
4. If you need to migrate for a third-party library in the future, for some of them like `react-native-extended-stylesheet`, if you are using stylesheet, it will be easier.
5. You have some [methods](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet#methods) and [properties](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet#properties) that boost the development. For example, the property `StyleSheet.absoluteFill` will do `position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0`, or the method `compose()` will allow you to combine two styles, overriding it.

*P.S.: The performance answer looks to be a myth.*

**My opinion?**

Based on item 2 and 5, go to stylesheet instead of plain objects.

Answer (score 3):

I did not find any differences between `StyleSheet` and plain object, except of typing validation in TypeScript.

For example, this (note the typing differences):

```js
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import logo from './logo.svg';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.someViewStyle}>
        <Text style={styles.someTextStyle}>Text Here</Text>
        <Image style={styles.someImageStyle} source={logo} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles: StyleSheet.create({
  someViewStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    padding: 10,
  },
  someTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  someImageStyle: {
    height: 50,
    width: 100,
  },
});
```

equals to this:

```js
import { View, Text, Image, ViewStyle, TextStyle, ImageStyle } from 'react-native';
import logo from './logo.svg';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.someViewStyle}>
        <Text style={styles.someTextStyle}>Text Here</Text>
        <Image style={styles.someImageStyle} source={logo} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles: {
  someViewStyle: ViewStyle;
  someTextStyle: TextStyle;
  someImageStyle: ImageStyle;
} = {
  someViewStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    padding: 10,
  },
  someTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  someImageStyle: {
    height: 50,
    width: 100,
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the TypeScript example.

Answer (score 1):

Creating your styles via `StyleSheet.create` will pass though validation only when global variable `__DEV__` is set to true (or while running inside Android or IOS emulators see [React Native DEV and PROD variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33264515/787098))

**The function [source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0a6713312467d3f5b5dc993e91db9e7b1aa4fc8c/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js#L360) code is pretty simple:**

```
create < +S: ____Styles_Internal > (obj: S): $ReadOnly < S > {
  // TODO: This should return S as the return type. But first,
  // we need to codemod all the callsites that are typing this
  // return value as a number (even though it was opaque).
  if (__DEV__) {
    for (const key in obj) {
      StyleSheetValidation.validateStyle(key, obj);
      if (obj[key]) {
        Object.freeze(obj[key]);
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

I would recommend using it because it performs run-time validation during development, also it freezes the object.

Answer (score 1):

i know that this is a really late answer, but I've read that it shows you errors and provides auto completion in editors when you use `StyleSheet`.