# React native android build gradle debuggable false does not turn off __DEV__

Tags: android, build, variant

Hi I cannot found any answer solution for this

I have follwoing custom variant in `\android\app\build.gradle`

I have tried put `debuggable false`

But this does not changed `__DEV__` to false.

Everyone is telling debug variant and release variant but nobody is telling how exactly a specific toggle to change `__DEV__` to false.

Please help thanks.

```
buildTypes {

        alpha {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.dev

            debuggable false 
            
            ...
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"

            matchingFallbacks = ['release', 'debug']
        }
    }
```

also I have tried removed 'debug' from `matchingFallbacks` not working as well.

```
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
```

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaking you are looking at it wrong. As the link below mentions.

> You can use the **DEV** global variable in JavaScript to determine if you're using React Native packager or not. If you are running your app in the iOS Simulator or Android emulator **DEV** will be set to true.

[React Native DEV and PROD variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264431/react-native-dev-and-prod-variables)

As long as your running the app on emulators the `__DEV__` variable will be true.

You can try to run in a simulator with `--configuration Release`

Comment: I have tried both build apk and run in device , both stick to true

Comment: Thats because the emulator and running on real device still use the bundler. see my answer for a solution. I edited it.

Comment: it says unknown option

Comment: npx react-native run-android --configuration Release

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing this problem too, in my case the `buildType` name should contain "release" keyword. (don't ask me why)

Change `alpha` to `alphaRelease` and everything should works fine.

Example:

(I'm using RN 0.68.2)

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
        alphaRelease {
            initWith release
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']

            signingConfig signingConfigs.hmg
            debuggable false
            applicationIdSuffix ".hmg"
        }
        release {
            /* Add the firebaseCrashlytics extension (by default, it's disabled to improve build speeds) and set
            * nativeSymbolUploadEnabled to true along with a pointer to native libs. */
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
                unstrippedNativeLibsDir 'build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib'
            }

            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            debuggable false
            applicationIdSuffix ""
        }
    }
```